# Start an instance of Chrome without extensions or user preferences

Tags: google-chrome, screen-capture

Is it possible to start Google Chrome in a mode that doesn't have any extensions or bookmarks (or any other preferences). In other words, start it like it was a fresh install (but without deleting the current install).

I'd like to use Chrome in a screen capture but I don't want my extensions and bookmarks visible. I also don't want to be running in Incognito Mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use another profile in Chrome. In the new profile you have the option to port the things you want.

[Learn how to create new profile in Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824)

By default it will not have any extensions and will work like a fresh install.

**Note:** All your sessions and cookies will be limited to this profile only and will not be shared with previous profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same needs, as well as others, so I created a small macOS application that allows to launch and/or create profiles.

It's nothing else but a Google Chrome profile launcher, it's called Chrome Copilot and is available here: https://chromecopilot.com.

Hope it could help :)