# Open Google Chrome in a fresh Install Mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, safe-mode

I have a Google Chrome with all my bookmarks and extensions. But sometimes, I would like to Open Google Chrome in an absolutely fresh Install mode. I have tried different command line switches but it still keeps those bookmarks synced. Here are the switches I have tried so far.

`--disable-extensions`

`--incognito`

Both of these keep my bookmarks. I am looking for a way to quickly test in just a barebone google chrome installation (Just like a fresh installation).

Is that possible? I did my fair share of search, have even found list of all switches, but I am not sure which one should I try.

**Note**:

- I do not want to reset all my settings. I usually work with my extensions and bookmarks, this is for a quick test.
- Also, I know how to enable command line switch in Chrome, I do not need help with that.

Thank you all again, SuperUsers.

Comment: You should try launching Chrome with a different profile. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/473057/start-an-instance-of-chrome-without-extensions-or-user-preferences?rq=1) will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to create another profile in addition to the Default one.

#### What is a profile?

Definition from [Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en)):

> With profiles, you can keep all your Chrome info separate, like bookmarks, history, passwords, and other settings.

#### How?

1. clic on the top right image profile
2. then clic Add.

[image: add a new profile]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your replies. There are very useful. I ended up creating a new Google Chrome Shortcut on my desktop with the following switch.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --guest`

One caveat of this approach is that if I open a guest mode and next google chrome session will ask me about which profile to open. But that is acceptable for me, since I use `guest` mode sparingly for testing purposes.

Thank you all again.